# Java 8: read files with special characters in name

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, nio, tomcat8

I am trying to read files with special characters in name on a linux system. I don't have any control on the operating system.

I have tried using IO and NIO. I keep getting

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains
>   unmappable characters: /mnt/Au?enr?ckspiegel, elektrisch verstellbar, 1, edition-meta.xml

I can't really change a lot in the server, is there anything that I can do to solve this in my app?

```
System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset()); // US_ASCII
```

This gives me string with question marks for special characters "/mnt/Au?sen.xml"

```
Files.list(Paths.get(path)).forEach(file -> {
        log.info("file to string: " + file.toString());
        String correctedFileName = "";
        correctedFileName = new String(file.getFileName().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        log.info("corrected name: " + correctedFileName);
        try {
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(correctedFileName)));
            ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            while (entry != null) {
                Path filePath = Paths.get(unzipLocation, entry.getName());
                if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                    unzipFiles(zipInputStream, filePath);
                } else {
                    Files.createDirectories(filePath);
                }

                zipInputStream.closeEntry();
                entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you share the portion of the code where you were reading the file

Comment: Did you try to put StandardCharsets.UTF-8 instead of StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1?

Comment: Do you have the problems before or after you inserted that `new String(file.getFileName().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` thing?

Comment: Nothing helps, with it, without it.

Comment: In that case, you should not pollute your problem description with nonworking solution attempts. Keep it at a minimum. So what does your `log.info("file to string: " + file.toString());` produce? Is it a correct name string or is it already broken right at this place? Besides that, do you really have files directly in `/mnt/`? Further, when you get an exception, include its stack trace (based on the version without the solution attempt).

Comment: files not directly in mnt/ and file.toString() creates strings with question marks for special characters.

Comment: Well, if the system (or JVM) thinks, it’s US-ASCII, then all non-ASCII byte values are considered illegal, so they get replaced with the placeholder `?` right when the Java string is constructed. Of course, whatever you do afterwards, is pointless, as no transformation can bring back information which is not there. Since the string consists of ASCII characters only (this includes the question mark), reinterpreting the bytes as iso-latin-1 or UTF-8 has no effect anyway, as these encodings are supersets of ASCII, having exactly the same representation of pure ASCII strings.

Comment: Did you succeeded in solving this issue in the end ?

Comment: Yes, we had to some parameters in operating system.

Comment: Are you reffering to *-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8* or *-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8*. I have also assured that the locale are set to *en_US.UTF-8*: LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LANGUAGE=en_US:en, LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

you could try to parse the filename as a URI to solve such problems..

Sample:

```
File file = new File(path);
URI uri = file.toURI();
String asciiURI = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Comment: In your own solution above, did you try this ? `correctedFileName = new String(file.getFileName().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`